# asihttp using a POST method and post nsMutabledata to a uri,why i can not get the asi delegate callback?

Tags: http, ios4, httprequest, asihttprequest, objective-c-2.0

guys!
when i using asihttp in my app,i meant a post method with a nsmutabledata for body stream,but i can't get what should be,just couldn't callback the

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
```

**or**

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

delegate method. ASIFormDataRequest can't either
but Synchronous request is ok,just error for asynchronous.that's my request code below,how i can fit it for my app? thanks for any help!

```
ASIHTTPRequest* request=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostBody:data];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:30];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
```

That way you know for sure what methods the request should be calling when it's done.